# Segmented Tab IBAction won't pass to cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

My problem is that my segmented control won't pass information to my cellForRowAtIndexPath method in my tableView. When each tab is selected, I wanted to my table view to display different data.

Here is a snippet of my code from where I think my problem originates:

```
var parsedDataForTableView : ParseForDetailView? {
    didSet {
        self.selectedIndex = (parsedDataForTableView?.tabSelected)!
        self.tableView.rowHeight = (parsedDataForTableView?.tableViewRowHeight)!
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }
}

var selectedIndex = Int()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.parsedDataForTableView = ParseForDetailView(segmentedTabSelected: 0, primaryBarData: self.primaryBarDetails!, secondaryBarData: self.secondaryBarDetails!)
    configureView()
    configureNavigationBarItems()
    setImageShadow()

}

@IBAction func switchBetweenTabs(sender: AnyObject) {

    if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        print("Drinks Selected")
        self.selectedIndex = 0
        print(self.selectedIndex)
        self.parsedDataForTableView = ParseForDetailView(segmentedTabSelected: 0, primaryBarData: self.primaryBarDetails!, secondaryBarData: self.secondaryBarDetails!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        print("Entertainment Selected")
        self.selectedIndex = 1
        print(self.selectedIndex)
        self.parsedDataForTableView = ParseForDetailView(segmentedTabSelected: 1, primaryBarData: self.primaryBarDetails!, secondaryBarData: self.secondaryBarDetails!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        print("Info Selected")
        self.selectedIndex = 2
        print(self.selectedIndex)
        self.parsedDataForTableView = ParseForDetailView(segmentedTabSelected: 2, primaryBarData: self.primaryBarDetails!, secondaryBarData: self.secondaryBarDetails!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell  = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailViewCell") as! DetailViewCell
    print(self.selectedIndex)
    if self.selectedIndex == 0 {

        cell.drinkLabel.text = self.parsedDataForTableView?.drinksArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.priceLabel.text = self.parsedDataForTableView?.priceArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.entertainmentLabel.text = ""
    } else if self.selectedIndex == 1 {

        cell.entertainmentLabel.text = self.parsedDataForTableView?.entertainmentString
        cell.drinkLabel.text = ""
        cell.priceLabel.text = ""

    } else if self.selectedIndex == 2 {
       // finish this...
        cell.drinkLabel.text = "Info"
        cell.priceLabel.text = "Info"
        cell.entertainmentLabel.text = "Info"
    }

    return cell
}
```

So above we have my IBAction connected to my segmented tab and my cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I want to pass the selectedIndex property into the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to switch between the different data I want to display - initialized in my didSet up top.

When I run the code the view loads just fine with the first segment's information (0th segment index) displaying correctly and my print(self.selectedIndex) within my cellForRowAtIndexPath prints "0" for every cell printed as planned. When I tap the second and third segmented index that same print function prints nothing.

When I print the information inside my IBAction to the console everything is updating correctly.

Why does only my first index register with the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: what is ```ParseForDetailView(segmentedTabSelected: 0, primaryBarData: self.primaryBarDetails!, secondaryBarData: self.secondaryBarDetails!)``` doing? Is this actually changing the selected index? Also you are reloading your tableview everytime you select a new segment (this probably isn't your problem, just noticed it)

Comment: @NoName  The ParseForDetailView initialization is taking the data stored in primaryBarData and secondaryBarData and parsing it accordingly to the selected index on the segmented Tab on my UI.

Comment: maybe add a print statement to parsedDataForTableView to make sure it is working ```var parsedDataForTableView : ParseForDetailView? {
    didSet {
        self.selectedIndex = (parsedDataForTableView?.tabSelected)!
        print(self.selectedIndex)                                                self.tableView.rowHeight = (parsedDataForTableView?.tableViewRowHeight)!
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }
}```

Comment: @NoName the print(self.selectedIndex) prints the correct segmented tab index

Comment: You are setting the selectedIndex twice, once in ```switchBetweenTabs```, and then in ```parsedDataForTableView``` didSet.  Try taking it out of didSet.

Comment: @NoName didn't work : / Even if that was the case I would be setting it to the same value twice. For some only "0" still prints in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method when the first tab is selected but won't print "1" or "2" when the other tabs are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I may have mislead you to believe my problem lied somewhere in my logic. My problem was that in my numberOfRowsInSection I didn't account for all the three segmented tab cases therefore my data could not be displayed properly in the table view.

Thank you @NoName